# ReNative, Android Error - the path for SDK directory is like linked twice, cannot build, don't know why

Tags: react-native

I have created my first React Native (Android Wear OS) project and I cannot build it.

I don't understand why the path is linked twice. Can someone help me, please?

> rnv run -p androidwear - ERRROR! COMMAND:
>
> gradlew.bat assembleDebug -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
>
> FAILED with ERROR:
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > The SDK directory 'C:\Users\Dado\Desktop\mojaprva\platformBuilds\helloWorld_androidwear\Users\Dado\AppData\Local\Android\sdk' does not exist.

Comment: hey you are running your app on real device right??

Comment: no, on emulator

Comment: Check C:\Users\Dado\.rnv\renative.json and set right ANDROID_SDK path, looks like copy paste error, path will be probably just '\Users\Dado\AppData\Local\Android\sdk'